# Color scale for curves in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some image data plotted using color scale. I want to pick out a line from the image and plot the curve in ggplot2, using the same color scale on the curve, as I do in the image. Is this possible?

Suppose I plot my image as follows

```
require(ggplot2)
n <- 100 # number of observations
cols <- topo.colors(256) # color scheme
lim <- c(-10, 10) # limits corresponding to color scheme

x <- seq(0, 1, length = n) # x-axis
y <- cumsum(rnorm(n)) # Brownian motion

dat <- data.frame(x, y) # data

# Plot
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(limits = lim)
```

[image: Resulting plot]

I want to color the line similarly to the following plot

[image: Color scale plot]

Created with the following code

```
colscale <- function(y, cols, ylim) {
    k <- length(cols)
    steps <- seq(ylim[1], ylim[2], length = k)

    result <- sapply(y, function(x) {cols[which.min(abs(x - steps))]})
    return(result)
}

plot(x, y, ylim = lim, col = colscale(y, cols, lim))
```

Comment: I'm not a ggplot user, but with other plots I use something along the lines of colored line segments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward. You just need two things:

1. Specify the variable that colour changes with, in this case `y`
2. Add the colour palette.

So:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = lim) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=y)) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = topo.colors(256))
```

[image]